# Show that Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ includes open sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, borel-sets

> We know that we can generate the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$, denoted by $\mathcal{B}^n$, by the sets $I:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid a_i<x_i<b_i,~1\leq i\leq n\}$ where >$a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a_i<b_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.
>
> Show that $\mathcal{B}^n$ contains all open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**My approach:**

Let be $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an arbitrary open set. We consider an arbitrary $y\in M\cap\mathbb{Q}^n$ and define the set $E_y:=\{\epsilon\in(0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}\mid I_{\epsilon}(y)\subset M\}$, where
$$I_{\epsilon}(y):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid y_i-\epsilon<x_i<y_i+\epsilon\}.$$

As $M$ is open there exists at least one such $\epsilon >0$. WLOG $\epsilon\in(0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$. (If $\epsilon$ was not rational then we would take the next smaller value that is rational which obviously satisfies $I_{\epsilon}(y)\subset M$)

The union $\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)$ is countable and as mentioned at the beginning each set $I_{\epsilon}(y)$ is a Borel-set. By the properties of a $\sigma$-algebra $\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\in \mathcal{B}^n$. The same argument holds if we consider $\bigcup\limits_{y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\right)$ and hence $\bigcup\limits_{y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\right)\in \mathcal{B}^n$.

Now we show that $M=\bigcup\limits_{y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\right)$.

The property $M\supseteq\bigcup\limits_{y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\right)$ is trivial as the sets $I_{\epsilon}(y)$ are constructed appropriately.

Now we turn to $M\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\right)$.

If we take a $y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n$ we immediately see that $y\in\bigcup\limits_{y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\right)$.

If $x\in M\setminus\mathbb{Q}^n$ then it gets a bit more complicated:

As $M$ is open we find a $\epsilon>0$ such that $I_{\epsilon}(x)\subset M$. WLOG we assume $\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$. Of course $I_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x)\subset M$. As $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we find a $y\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ such that $y\in I_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x)$. We see that $x\in I_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(y) $ and. As $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is rational and $I_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(y) \subset I_{\epsilon}(x)\subset M$ we can conclude that $x \in \bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)$. Hence, $x\in \bigcup\limits_{y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\right)$ and finally $M=\bigcup\limits_{y\in M\cap \mathbb{Q}^n}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\epsilon\in E_y}I_{\epsilon}(y)\right)$.

Is this correct? Is there an easier way to show the part where $x\in M\setminus\mathbb{Q}^n$?

Comment: FYI, I didn't attempt to read your symbol forest. I think it will be simpler to understand, to  write down, and for someone to read if you do this in several relatively simple steps. First, every open ball centered at the origin is a union of appropriate cubes centered at the origin (have the cubes expand outward). Now any translation of a ball is also such a union (namely, of the corresponding translated cubes). How you continue depends on what you can use. For example, can you use the fact that any open set is a countable union of open balls with rational centers and rational radii?

Comment: *any translation of a ball* --- Probably need to change this to any "rational translation" (i.e. the vector for the translation has all rational components).

Comment: Use the fact that if $O$ is open, then $O$ is the union of all $J \in I$ such that $J$ has rational endpoints and $J \subset O$. In fact, with slightly more effort you can do even better: Every open set is a countable disjoint union of half open dyadic cubes (proof sketch: refine the grid).